# Bootloop at login screen of newly installed elementary OS

Tags: system-installation, boot

I installed the elementary OS Juno but at the time of starting the system it is looped in the login screen.

Processor Atom x5 z8350

How to fix this loop?

Comment: Please add your device specification in the body not in the title. And please add more information.

Comment: There are a couple of suggestions online about this, typically around Nvidia drivers. Does your computer have an Nvidia GPU?

Comment: Positivo Motion Q232a Atom x5 z8350 Intel Hd graphics integrated

Comment: I am facing a similar issue ... unable to login to elementary OS ans going into loops on login screen. I have important information and hence can’t just flash it and reinstall . Pls help